# SwiftUI: WebView doesn't load specific page

Tags: ios, webview, swiftui

I try to load a url in my WebView, it works well with "https://www.google.com", but it doesn't work with "https://www.sl.se".
It shows "Not Found, HTTP Error 404: The requested resource is not found."

[image]

The weird thing is that, if I google "sl.se" in Google page, click the sl.se, the the "www.sl.se" can be load the WebView. Does anyone know the reason?

ContentView.swift

```
// ContentView.swift

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var shouldRefresh = false
        var body: some View {
            VStack{
                Button(action: {
                    self.shouldRefresh.toggle()                    
                }){
                    Text("Reload")
                }
                WebView(url: nil, reload: $shouldRefresh)
            }
        }
}
```

WebView.Swift

```
// WebView.swift

import WebKit
import SwiftUI

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable{

    var url: URL?     // optional, if absent, one of below search servers used
    @Binding var reload: Bool

    private let urls = [URL(string: "https://google.com/")!, URL(string: "https://www.sl.se")!]
    private let webview = WKWebView()

    fileprivate func loadRequest(in webView: WKWebView) {
        if let url = url {
            webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        } else {
            let index = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970) % 2
            print("load: \(urls[index].absoluteString)")
            webView.load(URLRequest(url: urls[index]))
        }
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<WebView>) -> WKWebView {
        loadRequest(in: webview)
        return webview
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<WebView>) {
        if reload {
            loadRequest(in: uiView)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.reload = false     // must be async
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. You just need to remove the `www` from your URL. try `https://sl.se` and It'll work.